# Magento 2: Orders missing from database

Tags: magento2

Customers starting to contact us for their missing orders.

Somehow, they reached the success page and got a proper order increment_id.

Those increment ids are skipped from the `sales_order` table. Nowhere to be found.

No exception thrown in magento logs either.

We found entries like this in the `mysql log: [ERROR] InnoDB: (Duplicate key)` writing word node to FTS auxiliary index table.

Happens randomly and of course, it's impossible to reproduce.

Going crazy here, Please help me.

Comment: You can check the table `sales_sequence_meta`, look at the `sequence_table` for entity_type=order. Then check the records inside sequence_table specified. I suspect the corrupted records caused your issues.

Comment: Thanks, but all the records seem to be correct in sequence_order_1, and auto_increment is next in row.

Comment: The cause of error `Duplicate key` is too board that I cannot help you much. Most probably it's due to corrupted records from somewhere.

Comment: which magento 2 version are you using Mr Robert?

Comment: I'm on 2.2.6. Seems the issue is redis related: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18277.

Comment: @RobertSchmidt same issue here could you tell me how you fixed it or debug this ?